# Removing rows in data validation in Excel

Tags: excel, list, menu

I am trying to remove a couple of rows in a data validation list menu pulled from another sheet.

Tried to just add the row ranges like this:

'Ingredients 5.8.18'!A4:A15, a17:a28, a28,a31

Rows in between are headers or labels.

The above example does not work.

It will work with the whole range 'Ingredients 5.8.18'!A1:A50.

Comment: You could generate a single range using formulas referring to the non-contiguous ranges, and have data validation point to that one.

Comment: What would that look like in Excel language?

Comment: `=A4`, `=A5` ...`=A14`, `=A15`, `=A17`, `=A18`... and so on

Comment: I was hoping to just have ranges and lone rows. Doing a4:a19, a22, a24.